# How to navigate to a ShellRoute with go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, flutter-routes

I have a shell route called **BasePage** with routes such as **HomePage**. I want the first screen of my app to be another page called **FirstPage**. Then, I want to navigate from **FirstPage** to **BasePage**. However, **BasePage** doesn't have a path, so when I use `context.push(<path_of_home_page>);`, **HomePage** doesn't have a scaffold and it's missing the bottom app bar. How can I navigate to the shell route?

***EDIT***
Adding the shell route:

```
ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      pageBuilder: (_, __, child) => NoTransitionPage(child: BasePage(child: child)),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: Paths.home,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: HomePage(),
          ),
        ),
        // ...
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Please provide the code used to define shell routes